# 2000's cartoon where a six-fingered pianist gets his extra finger(s?) removed for the girl he likes

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107313/looking-for-a-work-of-sf-featuring-six-fingered-humanoids) being recently brought back from the dead triggered a memory of sorts, and I'd like to put a name to it.

## General info:

- Saw this on a French TV channel, somewhere between 2005 and 2010. Possible channels I saw that on: TF1, France 2, France 3, M6. Doesn't mean it wasn't being broadcasted on other channels, but those are the ones I'm likely to have seen it on.
- The language was French, but it could have been from non-French origin.
- The cartoon was probably made between 1990 and 2010.
- Likely a kids cartoon. In color, as many of them are.
- I think this was an episode from a series.
- I'm pretty sure it was a cartoon (Western animation) and not an anime, since I tend to remember Japanese-like animation, but I may be wrong.

## Plot:

I remember that there was a guy who could play the piano really well because he had one extra finger - possibly one of each hand, I'm not sure, but at least one. He gets along with a girl, and the girl made some comment about how it was unusual/strange to have an extra finger. Later on, the guy gets his extra finger(s) removed because he thinks the girl would like him better if he did so.

Both the guy and the girl would have been in their teen years/early twenties.

I can remember him showing his closed fist, fingers towards him, to the girl and "deploying" his fingers one by one until she can realize there are "only" five of them. Like when we count on our fingers (the European way at least):

[image: French/German system]

*(above: French/German/Spanish system; below: English system)*
[image: English finger count system]

The girl is stunned, and says something like:

> But you won't be able to play the piano anymore!

## Additional info:

- Somehow I think it might have taken place in a school, but this is blurry.
- A slice of life maybe?
- "Why is it sci-fi?" Well, extra fingers exist in real life (polydactyly), but not to a point where they're considered "normal". Also, the removing part did not seem to be a big deal. The girl was stunned by the *why*, not the *how*. I don't think the guy was engineered (like the one in *Gattaca*), but that's not impossible.

## Research I've done:

- It's not among [these questions about six-fingered beings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D%20six%20finger%20is%3Aquestion). Three of them are written works​ anyway.
- The ["Extra Digits" list](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExtraDigits) (Warning: TVTropes link!) doesn't ring any bells.

Comment: A story about a regular polydactyl person getting surgery would be unusual, but not SF. However, I am sure you remember the tone, so I bet there will be SF elements.

Comment: @Adamant can't think of any right now, but I'll try to think about it. I know it doesn't prove much, but the only TV I'd watch would be SF/superhero/fantasy/not-set-in-the-real-world. Well, I'll sleep on it and see if anything comes back!

Comment: A woman complaining about a man having too many fingers...hmmm...that's sci-fi for sure.

Comment: Per [this deleted (non-)answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/284599/98028), someone looking for a similar cartoon remembered _"an old man gave the boy a caterpillar that ate his sixth finger"_. Adding this as a comment if that proves helpful in the search.

Answer (score -3):

May be [*Gravity Falls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Falls).

> Stanford Pines, also known as The Author, Ford and Grunkle Ford (voiced by J. K. Simmons) – Grunkle Stan's six-fingered long-lost twin brother. He is introduced in the eleventh episode of season 2, having briefly appeared in a silent capacity in previous episodes.

Comment: Unless the OP is remembering the years (1990-2010) incorrectly, it can't be Gravity Falls. Per your link, Gravity Falls premiered in 2012.

Comment: Does he have his fingers removed to impress a girl?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks ​for your answer but no, that's not it, it's both too recent and a quick Google search doesn't seem to yield such a scene.